# What is context token in guava TypeToken explained?

Tags: guava

In the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ReflectionExplained):

> resolveType is a powerful but complex query operation that can be used to "substitute" type arguments from the ***context token***. For example,

So, what is context token? have something to do with TypeResolver??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example that follows this sentence explains it:

```
TypeToken<Function<Integer, String>> funToken = new TypeToken<Function<Integer, String>>() {};

TypeToken<?> funResultToken = funToken.resolveType(Function.class.getTypeParameters()[1]));
```

// returns a TypeToken

In this example, the "context" token is `funToken`, i.e. the token on which resolveType() is called, and which thus provides the "context" of the query that `resolveType()` executes.